# Access modifiers and inheritance

Tags: c#, class, struct, interface, access-modifiers

I am trying to get a class to only be allowed to be initialized with `new` keyword inside the scope of the namespace. Though I need to be able to use it's `type` example

```
namespace MyNameSpace {

   class MyClass {

      public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   class NewMyClass {
       MyClass cls = new MyClass();
       cls.Name = "My Name";
   } 
}
```

But on `Program.cs` I want the user only to be able to do the following.

```
NewMyClass myC = new NewMyClass();
List<MyClass> myList = myC.method();

foreach(MyClass a in myList){
    Console.WriteLine(a.property);
}
```

As you can hopefully see I want to have them use it as a datatype since it'll be the type of list it'll need to be. But I don't want the user to set `Name` in `MyClass` nor be able to call `new MyClass`. I've tried making `MyClass` into an interface but I need to create new instances to store inside the `List`.

I've also tried setting `private set` so that only `NewMyClass` can set them but that didn't work either. I've been reading this for a while and I am just so stuck!

What I want user to be able to do~!

```
List<MyClass> //use as a datatype
Console.WriteLine(a.property); //call the property from the list
```

What I don't want the user to do!

```
new MyClass();
a.property = "Other Name" //set the value.
```

**Reasons**

There will be no reason for the user to call `MyClass` only the NewMyClass should call it. Also there will be no reason for the user to assign the value to any property in `MyClass`. I am using a class because I was told not to use a `struct` which is ok since I'm liking the versatility of the class method so far. But I need to limit a lot from the user.

If I am going the wrong with this please let me know, I am very new to C# so please don't be afraid to tell me which way you'd go and why so I can understand your reasoning.

**Step two of thinking**

Back to a struct method. I now have

```
internal struct MyClass {
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

What I like about this is that when I do

```
MyClass cls = new MyClass();
```

It gives a warning showing that the `cls` is assigned but never used. But then when we do

```
cls.Name = "google";
```

That warning goes away and that defeats that I don't want the user to set, but only my main class to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot limit access by `namespace`.  The access modifier that is closest to what you are looking for is `internal`, which limits scope to a given assembly.

If you put `MyClass` and `NewMyClass` in the same assembly and you set the access modifier of the `MyClass` constructor to `internal`, you would be on your way to a solution.

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: Would this defeat the purpose of using it as a datatype?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 'MyClass' public but it's members 'internal'. Of course, 'internal' only works if these classes are in a separate assembly.

```
namespace MyNameSpace {

   public class MyClass {

       internal string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public class NewMyClass {
       MyClass cls = new MyClass();
       cls.Name = "My Name";
   } 
}
```

Comment: Did what you have, (back to a class), and these members are still accessible to the user in `Program.cs` if the call `MyClass cls = new MyClass()`

Comment: @EasyBB, you need to put them in a separate project assembly (DLL)

Comment: Both of them together like you have?

Comment: @EasyBB, Yes, put both in the separate assembly. Otherwise `NewMyClass` won't have access to the `internal`s of `MyClass`.

Comment: Ok I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

While it is really hard to limit creation to just one type that is not in inheritance chain (due to lack if [accessibility level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) that you need ) you can do tricks with nested types.

```
class NewMyClass {

  private static Func<MyClass> create = null;

  public class MyClass {
    public static void Init() { NewMyClass.create = ()=> new MyClass();}
    private MyClass(){ }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public MyClass Method(){
    MyClass.Init(); 
    MyClass cls = create();
    cls.Name = "My Name";
    return cls;
  }
}
```

`private` constructor of `MyClass` prevents creation by anyone directly.

static helper `MyClass.Init()` lets its outer class initilaize private delegate to create the instance. Nested class can set the outer class' private delegate - so both have to cooperate to allow protection you want.

Note that more reasonable approach would be to have `MyClass` to be abstract (or interface) and provide `private` implementations inside `NewMyClass` - you may find such approach easier to test too.

Comment: Yeah I am really new, so abstract and interface are all new to me. And while using the interface the compiler errors out saying you can't call new on interface. I need to have new instances of `MyClass` because there will be 100s of them in a `List` that al should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you can separate it out in separate Assemblies as Glenn has already pointed it out it will be best. 
And then you need an Interface & a Factory Method.

Also I tried to change your program so it uses interfaces -

```
    namespace MyNameSpace {



       public interface IMyClass
        {
            string Name { get; }
        }

       internal class MyClass : IMyClass  {

          public string Name { get; internal set; }
       }

       class NewMyClass {


           private IMyClass Init(string name)
           {
               MyClass cls = new MyClass();
               cls.Name = name;
               return cls;
           }

         public List<IMyClass> method()
           {
              var collection = new List<IMyClass>();

              collection.Add(Init("1st Sample"));
              collection.Add(Init("2nd Sample"));

              return collection;
           }

       } 
    }

    namespace UserNameSpace
    {

        public class Prog
        {
            public static void Func()
            {

                NewMyClass myC = new NewMyClass();
                List<IMyClass> myList = myC.method();

                foreach (IMyClass a in myList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, if both the namespaces are in the same assembly, the user will be able to instantiate the class anyway.